# How did Uther Doul capture The Brucolac?

Tags: china-mieville, the-scar

The Brucolac is an old, extremely powerful ab-dead.  The Lieutenants he created are, by themselves, physically superior to even small groups of armed, ready, trained guards, yet it was mentioned that The Brucolac has easily and effortlessly squashed every act of rebellion or attempt to overthrow him.

It stands to reason that his experience, power, and ab-dead status would make him more than a match for even the strongest, most experienced mortal warrior.

Yet Uther Doul not only defeated The Brucolac, but did so seemingly without suffering any injury, and actually managed to subdue, without killing.

It's been established that Doul is a superb warrior, and able to defeat enemies through seemingly super-human feats.  However, the displays of his prowess throughout the book can either be attributed to his mastery of his very precise fighting style, or his mastery of probability mining and his possible sword.

His performance during the capture of the *Terpsichoria* is almost certainly through use of the possible sword.

His defeat of the scabmettler gladiators can be explained by being a truly masterful warrior (I don't recall if he turned on the possible sword or not, but a single warrior defeating three other trained warriors through superior skill alone is not outside of the realm of popular tropes).

Even his defeat of the Anophelli women could be attributed to highly trained reflexes, as even though they move incredibly fast, the Anophelli women are single-minded in their need to feed, seeming incapable of more complex tactics than simply charging their prey head-on.

Yet The Brucolac is incredibly fast, intelligent, and strong.

I don't see how Doul could have defeated The Brucolac without switching on his possible sword.  However, Doul described his fighting techniques as two separate, generally opposite styles.

When he has his sword switched off, he relies on precision.  Precision doesn't work when the sword is switched on, though.  The sword makes *every possible strike* varying degrees of real. The results are typically extremely messy, as dozens, or even hundreds, of possible strikes land with each attack, generally puréeing whatever is on the receiving end.

So how do Doul's options of "incredibly precise, but mortal-level" or "incredibly imprecise, but supernaturally destructive" fighting styles result in an easy capture of an old, experienced, and ready vampir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the idea that there was no fight. I find it doubtful that the Brucolac would just agree to let Doul capture him and string him up in the sun. I think he is too proud and too concerned with his image of a big scary vampir, especially since he's convinced that the only way to live amongst humans is to make sure they are scared of you.

Earlier Doul mentions to Bellis how he re-learned to fight with the possible sword, and that in order to maximize damage you need to make very unprecise hits. Hence, if you aim really well all mined possible hits fall really close to the actual hit making damage not that much greater than it would be with the sword off. Conversely, if you make sloppy, intuitive, unplanned hits the possibilities are much broader and when they materialize they literally mince the body.

SO, if Doul's goal was to subdue the brucolac, but not mince him into pulp, he could have tuned the precision of his attacks just enough for the brucolac to survive. I'd bet he could tune the damage he does with his sword by having it on, but just making his attacks a tad more precise so the possibilities dont fan out as much. Like the previous poster mentioned he probably pre-engineered the fight and went thru the options in order to make sure he uses the correct amount of precision.

anyhow, that's my 50 cents.

Answer (score 3):

It struck me on reflection that Doul and the Brucolac had very similar aims (ending the quest). So maybe there was no fight.  The Brucolac made a deal to strengthen Douls position, thus the Brucolac was playing the long game.
Maybe Doul convinced him that was the only way to get the result both wanted.
After all, the Brucolac walked away at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I can see several possibilities:

- As you say, the Brucolac is supernaturally strong. He may simply have been tough enough to endure Doul's attack.
- The final chapters heavily imply that Doul's abilities in probability-mining are far broader than brute combat. He may have engineered any number of scenarios that put the Brucolac at a disadvantage.

However my preferred explanation is more psychological. Throughout the early parts of the book, the Brucolac's relationship with Doul carries the assumption that Doul does not support The Lovers plan. The Brucolac acted assuming Doul would support him - or at least stand aside when push came to shove. Faced with the realisation that Doul was standing against him, the Brucolac may have chosen to surrender rather than be defeated.